# Refactor two similar functions with different inner for-loop

Tags: c#

I want to reduce code duplication in my project. At one point I have a static Helper class, with two methods `Create` and `Delete`, which look something like this:

```
public static void Create(List container)
{
    // cannot use foreach, because container elements could be deleted
    for(var i = 0; i < container.Count; i++)
    {
        var operation = new Creator(container[i]);
        operation.Exec();
        operation.Dispose();
    }
}

public static void Delete(List container)
{
    // cannot use foreach, because container elements could be deleted
    for(var i = 0; i < container.Count; i++)
    {
        var operation = new Deleter(container[i]);
        operation.Exec();
        operation.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So you see, the methods have the same outer construct, the for-loop and then create a Operation, they then execute. `Deleter` and `Creator` have the same base class. The methods are longer in real but the statements are all the same except the `var operation new ...()`

How can I change this code, that it isn't duplicate anymore?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tbh, I'd care less about the duplication for now but about the excessive creation/destruction of "Operation" objects.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Comment: @Fildor call it how you want. This is a simplification of the real problem.

Comment: Ok, then. As I said, maybe you need to step back a little further and question the design. And MickyD has a point there about the question being off topic for SO, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the design advice, but I have to implement to a given interface, which I can't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a method* (`Perform`) with `builder` lambda function added to create either `Creator` or `Deleter`:

```
private static void Perform(List container, Func<object, Operation> builder)
{
    // cannot use foreach, because container elements could be deleted
    foreach (var item in container)
      using (var operation = builder(item))
      { 
         operation.Exec();  
      } 
}

public static void Create(List container) => Perform(list, (item) => new Creator(item));

public static void Delete(List container) => Perform(list, (item) => new Deleter(item));
```

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that creating a new short-lived object in each iteration has some smell to it, Dmitry? EDIT: OP has no choice about that => +1

Comment: @Fildor: I doubt if we can avoid this (create one `Creator`/`Deleter` and assign `container` items to it): we know nothing about `Creator` / `Deleter` size of `container` (and why it's of type List` and not, say `List<T>`); when more code provided (with initial problem included) we could elaborate a better implementation

Comment: Agreed. I guess that's why MickyD voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a helper method which gets a delegate to create the object

```
private static Execute(List<SomeClass> container, Func<Someclass, BaseClass> create)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < container.Count; i++)
    {
        var operation = create(container[i]);
        operation.Exec();
        operation.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And in your original Methods you'd call it like so:

```
public static void Create(List<SomeClass> container) =>
    Execute(container, x => new Creator(x));

public static void Delete(List<SomeClass> container) =>
    Execute(container, x => new Deleter(x));
```

I'm assuming here that `container` is a generic list.